# XML to JSON conversion in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, json

i'm trying to convert a simple xml document in Xcode to JSON. The problem is keep returning nil.

This is my code:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:@"http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml"];
NSData *xmlData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSError *parseError = nil;
NSDictionary *xmlDictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:xmlData error:&parseError];


NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:xmlDictionary
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                     error:&error];
 NSLog(@"%@", jsonData);
```

Error message:

```
[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: value parameter is nil'
```

Comment: Clearly `xmlDictionary` is `nil`. Log `parseError` to see why.

Comment: Still returns [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: value parameter is nil'

Comment: You misunderstand. `xmlDictionary` is `nil`. This means your call to `dictionaryForXMLData:error:` is returning `nil`. What do you get when you log `parseError` from the call to `dictionaryForXMLData:error:`.

Comment: In other words, **When xmlDictionary is nil, log parseError!!**

Comment: Uh, `initFileURLWithPath` is expecting the path of a file on the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As rmaddy said, try printing parseError. If parseError is Nil, then try printing the xmlDictionary, and check if the dictionary is created correctly.

If xmlDictionary is also Nil, then check the xmlData, which should be fine, in which case the dictionaryForXMLData method must be verified if it checks for any conditions.

Hope I helped.

Comment: xmlDictionary returns (null). xmlData returns null. I guess it is something with xmlData?

Comment: If xmlData is Nil, then try initializing the NSData in the below method
[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http ://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml"]]

Comment: The data is not a "file".  `initWithContentsOfFile` will not work.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say initWithContentsOfURL:options:error:

Comment: @anirudh You have things backwards. If `xmlDictionary` is `nil`, only then should you check `parseError`. In virtually all methods that take an `NSError **` parameter, you must only check the resulting error if the return value of the method indicates there might be an error. In most cases this is when the method returns `nil`. Never rely of the value of the error parameter as the primary check for an error.